# Prove an homomorphism on groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

How can I show that the map $\theta:S_4\rightarrow S_3$ defined by $θ(g) = g^∗$ is an homomorphism.
I've been trying this problem and I can only prove for all the cases which is exhausting, how can I show directly that it's an homomorhpism.

$g^*$ is the the permutation induced on the partitions. That is with a permutation we substitute each element on the partition by its' next element on the permutation.

For example,if
$$A = \{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}\}; \\
B = \{\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}\}; \\
C = \{\{1, 4\}, \{2, 3\}\}.$$
and if g is the cyclic permutation (1, 2, 3, 4), then $g^∗ = (A, C)(B)$.

Comment: I am not sure what $g^*$ denotes here

Comment: I edited, sorry

Answer (score 0):

An action of a group $G$ on a set $E$ gives rise to a group morphism: $G\to S(E)$, sending $g\in G$ to the permutation $\sigma_g: x\in E\mapsto g\cdot x\in E$.

You can check that this map is indeed a morphism just using the group action axioms (the fact that $\sigma_g$ is bijective comes from the fact that an inverse is $\sigma_{g^{-1}}$, again using the definition on a group action)

Your map is exactly the morphism you obtain with the action you describe in your post...